# Twitter request token

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to work with the examples on the Twitter dev site but can't seem to get to the same signature as they have.

I am trying to complete step 3 on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter because I am getting an error "Invalid or expired token" but I know it isn't because I've only just been given it, so it must be something wrong with my data packet.

The code I am using to try and generate this is:

```
// testing bit
$oauth = array(
        'oauth_consumer_key'=>'cChZNFj6T5R0TigYB9yd1w',
        'oauth_nonce'=>'a9900fe68e2573b27a37f10fbad6a755',
        'oauth_signature_method'=>'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_timestamp'=>'1318467427',
        'oauth_token'=>'NPcudxy0yU5T3tBzho7iCotZ3cnetKwcTIRlX0iwRl0',
        'oauth_version'=>'1.0'            
);            
$this->o_secret = 'LswwdoUaIvS8ltyTt5jkRh4J50vUPVVHtR2YPi5kE';
$this->c_secret = 'kAcSOqF21Fu85e7zjz7ZN2U4ZRhfV3WpwPAoE3Z7kBw';    

ksort($oauth);

$string = rawurlencode(http_build_query($oauth));

$new_string = strtoupper($http_method).'&'.rawurlencode($main_url[0]).'&'.$string;

// The request_token request doesn't need a o_secret because it doesn't have one!
$sign_key = strstr($fullurl,'request_token') ? $this->c_secret.'&' : $this->c_secret.'&'.$this->o_secret; 

echo urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',$new_string,$sign_key,true)));exit;
```

And I'm assuming that the keys listed on this page are in fact correct: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature. So in that case the signature should be 39cipBtIOHEEnybAR4sATQTpl2I%3D.

If you can spot what I'm missing that would be great.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to be sharing your `*_secret` tokens publicly. They are **secret** for a reason.

Comment: Thanks - no these come from Twitters official site. I was trying to replicate their examples to see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your consumer secret and token secret are incorrect for the [page you reference](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter). If you look further up the page you can see that they should be:

```
Consumer secret: L8qq9PZyRg6ieKGEKhZolGC0vJWLw8iEJ88DRdyOg
Token secret: veNRnAWe6inFuo8o2u8SLLZLjolYDmDP7SzL0YfYI
```

Also in Step 3 you need to include the `oauth_verifier` in the list of parameters when calculating your signature base string.

I'm not familiar with PHP so I haven't checked your code to calculate the signature.

Comment: Sorry I was using this page as my example (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature) which doesn't appear to include the verifier in the code. Will crack on.

Answer (score 0):

This code has now worked - I will tidy it up from there :)

```
    // This function is to help work out step 3 in the process and why it is failing
    public function testSignature(){
            // testing bit
            $oauth = array(
                    'oauth_consumer_key'=>'cChZNFj6T5R0TigYB9yd1w',
                    'oauth_nonce'=>'a9900fe68e2573b27a37f10fbad6a755',
                    'oauth_signature_method'=>'HMAC-SHA1',
                    'oauth_timestamp'=>'1318467427',
                    'oauth_token'=>'NPcudxy0yU5T3tBzho7iCotZ3cnetKwcTIRlX0iwRl0',
                    'oauth_version'=>'1.0'            
            );

            $this->o_secret = 'LswwdoUaIvS8ltyTt5jkRh4J50vUPVVHtR2YPi5kE';
            $this->c_secret = 'kAcSOqF21Fu85e7zjz7ZN2U4ZRhfV3WpwPAoE3Z7kBw';    

            ksort($oauth);

            $string = http_build_query($oauth);

            $new_string = strtoupper($http_method).'&'.$main_url[0].'&'.$string;

            $new_string = 'POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&include_entities%3Dtrue%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog%26oauth_nonce%3DkYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1318622958%26oauth_token%3D370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DHello%2520Ladies%2520%252B%2520Gentlemen%252C%2520a%2520signed%2520OAuth%2520request%2521';

            // The request_token request doesn't need a o_secret because it doesn't have one!
            $sign_key = $this->c_secret.'&'.$this->o_secret; 

            echo 'Should be: tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk/jLY=<br>';
            echo 'We get: '.base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1',$new_string,$sign_key,true));
            exit;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to access token from twitter and sign in implementation you can see in this example.

1) http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-twitter-using-php/

and this one for timeline tweets

2) http://www.codexworld.com/create-custom-twitter-widget-using-php/

may be this help you .